# show and hide if end of url equals?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide and show a DIV if the end of a URL equals = #trending

I have a function that does most of it, i'm just not sure how to get the very end of the url of the current page.

```
function hideLgFooter() {
    var url = document.location.toString();
    var checkUrl = ;

    if (checkUrl == '#trending'){
        $('.footer-lg').show();
        $('.footer-sm').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: if (checkUrl == '#trending'){ this condition will never execute inner code because it will fail everytime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash`:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#trending') {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use `split`.

```
function hideLgFooter() {
    var url = document.location.toString().split('#');
    var checkUrl = ;

    if (url[1] == 'trending')
    {
        $('.footer-lg').show();
        $('.footer-sm').hide();
    }
}
```

Try above and see if it's work.

Comment: @Blender yeah i accidentally wrote it..sorry for my bad...i know split is a core part of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _url = location.href;
var _reg = /(#trending)$/;
_reg.test(_url);
```

so

```
    if (_reg.test(_url)){
      $('.footer-lg').show();
      $('.footer-sm').hide();
    }
```